# Is there a native function of what I am trying to achieve?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I've written a function which seems to be a common task, I've been looking through the php documentation and can't find this function

```
/**
 * Move certain key/values from an array to a new one
 * @param array $array the original array
 * @param array $keys
 * @return $array
 */
function array_rip(array &$array, array $keys){
    $new = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(isset($array[$key])){
            $new[$key] = $array[$key];
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $new;
}
```

Is there already a function like this and I just missed the obvious?

this is the behavior

```
<?php
$a = array('color'=>'green', 'fruit'=>'apple','item_id'=>33,'owner_id'=>420);
$b = array_rip($a,array('owner_id','item_id'));

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [fruit] => apple
)

Array
(
    [owner_id]  => 420
    [item_id]  => 33
)
```

Comment: not as far as I know, but you can look at the documentation, the closest thing which resembles this is http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php, but the number of keys must equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it to this; I don't think it will be more efficient though.

```
function array_rip(array &$array, array $keys)
{
  $new = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
  $array = array_diff($array, $new);
  return $new;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

```
$array = array_combine(array_keys($array1), array_values($array2));
```

Comment: `array_combine()` requires that both the arrays have the same number of items, or you get the error "Both parameters should have an equal number of elements." Also, the OP wants to keep only the keys that match the values contained in the second array.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such function, but what you are trying can be achieved with following code

```
$arr1 = array('one' => 'one_v', 'two' => 'two_v', 'three' => 'three_v');
$arr2 = array('one', 'three');

// flip, so keys become values
$arr1_flipped = array_flip($arr1);

array_flip(array_diff($arr1_flipped, $arr2)); // returns Array([two] => two_v)

array_flip(array_intersect($arr1_flipped, $arr2)) // returns Array ([one] => one_v  [three] => three_v)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use array flip function like what @Artem L suggested you can achieve what you want but it will take little bit extra processing time as it is calling array_flip 3 times to achieve what you want.

array_combine will not satisfy your need.

array_rip is not available in php. So I would suggest that you have algorithm i.e. logic ready for your function. create functions.php in your project and add your function in this file. include this file in your code and then you can use this function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 5.1.0, or higher, you can use [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php), as in the following code.

```
function array_rip(array &$array, array $keys) {
  $result = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
  $array = array_diff($array, $result);

  return $result;
}
```